# error printing report <traceback object at 0x06F19DC8>)?

Tags: python-2.7, openerp-7, openoffice-writer, rml

I want to print a report. I have a module named partnership is under the addons folder. and under the partnership folder I carry the folder that contains new_report.rml new_report.sxw and new_report.py class containing this code:

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class new_report(report_sxw.rml_parse):
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
    super(new_report, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
    self.localcontext.update( {'time': time,})

report_sxw.report_sxw('report.new.report', 'contratcommercial',
                  'addons/partnership/report/new_report.rml',
                  parser=new_report)
```

under addons / partnership partnership I report.xml containing this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<report
  auto="False"
  id="new_report_id"
  model="contratcommercial"
  name="commercial_report"
  rml="partnership/report/new_report.rml"
  string="imprimer contrat "/>

 </data>
 </openerp>
```

but I still have this error

```
report.commercial_report (<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, KeyError(u'report.commercial_report',), <traceback objectat 0x06F19DC8>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your report id is given wrong.`name` attribute of `<report> tag` is same as in `.py` side. Just put ahead `report` for example `report.name.value`

Try this code.

**in .py side**

```
report_sxw.report_sxw('report.commercial.report', 'contratcommercial',
              'addons/partnership/report/new_report.rml',
              parser=new_report)
```

**in .xml side**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
    <report
    auto="False"
    id="new_report_id"
    model="contratcommercial"
    name="commercial.report"
    rml="partnership/report/new_report.rml"
    string="imprimer contrat "/>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: thnx Oderda for your answer, i have changed the code but no chnages